# Job queue always failed to sync data into api/graphql with Getting unknown property of service

Tags: php, modules, services, queue, phpstorm

i have build a module to send entry value into a graphql mutation.
so far running and succesfully,
now with craft 4 (actually as 4.4.0), i plan to use job queue of craft.
i add into queue before sync with priority 10 and always got failed within message

`Getting unknown property: asd\ModName\Module::syncService`

i have tried to find related issue and solver but nothing,

anyone have same issue ?

or any clue for Getting unknown property ?

Comment: we also build another modules and use queue job to send revalidation (a sample job) and result ok

Answer (score 1):

Search for that error in `storage/runtime/logs`. There should be a stack trace getting logged alongside the error, which can help you understand where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: thanks, i got this 
```2023-03-14 11:50:44 [queue.ERROR] [yii\base\UnknownPropertyException] yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Getting unknown property: asd\modname\Module::syncService in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(77): yii\base\Component->__get()
#1 /var/www/html/modules/modname/jobs/ModNameJob.php(21): yii\di\ServiceLocator->__get()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/Queue.php(246): asd\modname\jobs\ModNameJob->execute()```

Comment: Finally fix, my bad place the register components services inside custom group permission